# No files checked in migration error

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Trying to migrate some version control data into Visual Studio Online from local TFS. Got the following error. I have retried multiple times and still get the same error.

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in.

Not sure where to go with this one. Is there somewhere I can get more details?

Comment: Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location :\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com